# Javascript: Array of dictionaries, get all key value pairs from one dictionairy with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, d3.js

First of all, this is my first post ever here and I'm not a very advanced programmer. If I don't follow the rules of Stackoferflow, please let me know.

I'm trying to make a scatterplot (and a datamap) for my linked-views assignment using D3. on my x-axis I will have years, on the Y axis I want the life Expectancy of a certain country. The country will be a variable and passed into the function that creates the scatterplot (by clicking on the datamap).

My dataset looks as follows:

```
    [{"country":"Abkhazia","1995":null,"1996":null,"1997":null,"1998":null,"1999":null,"2000":null,"2001":null,"2002":null,"2003":null,"2004":null,"2005":null,"2006":null,"2007":null,"2008":null,"2009":null,"2010":null,"2011":null,"2012":null,"2013":null,"2014":null,"2015":null,"2016":null},
     {"country":"Afghanistan","1995":49.4,"1996":49.7,"1997":49.5,"1998":48.6,"1999":50,"2000":50.1,"2001":50.4,"2002":51,"2003":51.4,"2004":51.8,"2005":52,"2006":52.1,"2007":52.4,"2008":52.8,"2009":53.3,"2010":53.6,"2011":54,"2012":54.4,"2013":54.8,"2014":54.9,"2015":53.8,"2016":52.72},
      etc.
```

My function starts like this:

```
function makeScatter(lifeExpectancy, healthPercGDP, country){...
```

I want to have an array or a dict of all the key value pairs or all the values (I think I could make both work) that belong to the country that is passed into my function (e.g. Afghanistan).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your data structure, an easy approach is just filtering the data array inside `makeScatter` function.

```
function makeScatter(country) {
    var filteredData = data.filter(d => d.country === country);
}
```

Here is a demo, check the console:

```js
var data = [{
  "country": "Abkhazia",
  "1995": null,
  "1996": null,
  "1997": null,
  "1998": null,
  "1999": null,
  "2000": null
}, {
  "country": "Afghanistan",
  "1995": 49.4,
  "1996": 49.7,
  "1997": 49.5,
  "1998": 48.6,
  "1999": 50,
  "2000": 50.1,
  "2001": 50.4
}, {
  "country": "Angola",
  "1995": 59.4,
  "1996": 59.7,
  "1997": 39.5,
  "1998": 58.6,
  "1999": 60,
  "2000": 60.1,
  "2001": 60.4
}];

function makeScatter(country) {
  var filteredData = data.filter(d => d.country === country);
  console.log(filteredData);
}

makeScatter("Afghanistan")
```

However, there is a potential problem here: in D3, the "enter" selection has as many elements as the array you pass to the `data()` function. Right now, this `filteredData` array has just one object, meaning that you'll have only one element in the enter selection.

Thus, my advice is this: after filtering your country, transform that huge object in an array of objects (each object having a `year` and an `expectancy` property), here named `countryData`:

```
function makeScatter(country) {
    var filteredData = data.filter(d => d.country === country);
    countryData = [];
    for (var prop in filteredData[0]) {
        countryData.push({
            year: +prop,
            expect: filteredData[0][prop]
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
  "country": "Abkhazia",
  "1995": null,
  "1996": null,
  "1997": null,
  "1998": null,
  "1999": null,
  "2000": null
}, {
  "country": "Afghanistan",
  "1995": 49.4,
  "1996": 49.7,
  "1997": 49.5,
  "1998": 48.6,
  "1999": 50,
  "2000": 50.1,
  "2001": 50.4
}, {
  "country": "Angola",
  "1995": 59.4,
  "1996": 59.7,
  "1997": 39.5,
  "1998": 58.6,
  "1999": 60,
  "2000": 60.1,
  "2001": 60.4
}];

function makeScatter(country) {
  var filteredData = data.filter(d => d.country === country);
  countryData = [];
  for (var prop in filteredData[0]) {
    countryData.push({
      year: +prop,
      expect: filteredData[0][prop]
    })
  }
  console.log(countryData)
}

makeScatter("Afghanistan")
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the quick and extensive response! Never heard of the .filter method before but it works perfectly. Could you maybe also elaborate on what happens here:

filter(d => d.country === country);

Comment: It filters your array, keeping only the objects in which `d.country` is equal to the argument you pass to the function.